About maximal torus of connected compact Lie group $SO(7).$
Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group. A "maximal torus" of $G$ is a closed connected Abelian $T$ such that if $T'\supset T$ is another such subgroup then $T'=T.$
And, we know that in $SO(2m+1),$ $T=\{\mathrm{diag}(R_1,R_2,...,R_m,1):R_i\in SO(2)\}\cong SO(2)^m.$
We have the fact:
If $g_1,g_2,g_3\in G,$ pairwise commute, then $g_1,g_2.g_3$ may not belong to a common maximal torus.
An example is to consider $g_1 = \mathrm{diag}(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1), g_2 = \mathrm{diag}(1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1), g_3 = \mathrm{diag}(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1).$
Is there any method to show that these three $g_1,g_2,g_3$ is not belong to a common maximal torus?(I think that $SO(2)\cong U(1)\cong S^1$ might be help, but still don't have other idea) Thank you!
